# Sqoop exec job - : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql..jdbc.Driver

Tags: mysql, sqoop

sqoop executive the job:sqoop job --skip-dist-cache --exec sqoop_full_bi_fact_autoloan_contract
The following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z26no.png)

and sqoop libs like :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCqCS.png)

So， why does the sqoop job fail

Comment: 22/07/02 16:13:08 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1611509189411_660101_m_000003_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:167)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:76)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)

Comment: sqoop jar list(/usr/loca/sqoop-1.4.6/lib/):
.....
mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar 
.....

Comment: Use version 8 of the mysql driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- go to this website : https://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/mysql/Downloads/Connector-J/

2- download a version of the connector (5.1.49.tar.gz is working fine for me)

3- extract the tar file using command : tar -zxf mysql-connector-java-5.1.49.tar.gz

4- put the extracted jar file in SQOOP_HOME/lib (SQOOP_HOME is where you have installed sqoop)